# GnuPG installed from source causing issue with Seahorse and GPA

Tags: compiling, gnupg, seahorse

I have installed GnuPG version 1.4.18 by building from source, so it got installed to /usr/local/bin. That causes issues with Seahorse as well as GPA because they keep looking for the application in /usr/bin. I see no way of changing GPG path from within Seahorse or GPA, so how do I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reconfigure the compilation using flags --prefix=/usr/bin

Be careful. It may breaks existing gpg package which comes preinstalled with ubuntu.

If you want to be safe, instead of manually compiling and installing, you should consider packaging it. [Learn more about Ubuntu packaging here](http://packaging.ubuntu.com).

Packaging is better than manual install, since packaged apps are tracked by apt package manager and easy to maintain (upgrade, uninstall, and reinstall)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I did install it using checkinstall.